# Uninstall application programmatically Android 10

Tags: android, android-10.0

I am developing an application which will uninstall itself after a button click. The following code works for the uninstallation of application running in Android.

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getClass().getPackage().getName(), null);
Intent uninst_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, uri);
startActivityForResult(uninst_intent, EXIT_REQUEST);
```

But this is not working for the new versions of android such as Android 9 and 10. This Action intent is not deprecated in the newer APIs. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is permission missing in Manifest please add this permission in manifest...

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES"></uses-permission>
```

this will work...!!!