# How can I create an app which deletes itself?

Tags: java, function, android-studio, self-destruction

How can i write a function that can remotely self-destruct it, ie delete that application from the phone?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.example.myapplication"));
startActivity(intent);
```

This code does not work on Android 10+

Comment: Any  errors or logs to show?
Try to look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60716057/uninstall-application-programmatically-android-10

Answer (score 0):

You can purge application files by enumerating app directory and deleting everything in there plus removing your application files on SD card. Uninstalling application itself is a different beast altogether. Non system apps cannot do that AFAIK (starting from android 2.0?).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).